# Distinguishing Pass-by-Reference and Pass-by-Value

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, ambiguity

How are pass-by-reference functions typically distinguished from pass-by-value functions?  For example:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& source); // Sorts source.

// Versus...

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> sort(std::vector<T> source); // Returns a sorted copy of source.
```

These two functions are ambiguous; one of them must be either renamed or removed completely.

How can this situation be avoided?  Should one form be preferred over the other?  Or are there any common naming guidelines to distinguish them?

Comment: Why is this a problem that needs solving? Since they're ambiguous, the compiler won't allow them to co-exist, and thus the problem will only last for as long as it takes to run the compiler, after which the programmer will go undo the previous change.

Comment: This is an issue about function signatures.  The signatures can be distinguished by the compiler if the second declaration passes by `const` reference.

Comment: is it really impossible to distinguish between the two functions in the OP question when calling? if yes, how, if not, wouldn't it be slightly better behavior if the c++ compiler gave an error even if the function is not called? I can compile with gcc version 4.6.3 without the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just give them different names? I would name the functional version `sorted`, for example.

Just because you *can* overload functions (or function templates in this case) does not mean you *have* to.

By the way, you can implement the "functional version" in terms of the "imperative version":

```
template <typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& source)
{
    // sort in place
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> sorted(std::vector<T> copy)
{
    sort(copy);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: "Just because you can overload doesn't mean you should" is gold.

Answer (score 2):

FredOverflow hit the nail on the head.  However, to answer your question "Or are there any common naming guidelines to distinguish them?" Just make sure you are consistent.  For example something like SortCopy for the second function name in your example.  It doesn't matter if it is SortCopy, SortCpy, Sort_Copy..   what does matter is that throughout your code, you are consistent (e.g.- all functions that act on a copy have the "Copy" prefix- not one having Copy, the next Cpy, etc...).

Comment: +1 that is what C++ library does: `std::reverse()`/`std::reverse_copy()`, `std::remove_if()`/`std::remove_copy_if()` and boost too `boost::to_lower()`/`boost::to_lower_copy()`

Answer (score 0):

It's typically preferred not to pass by non-const reference if possible and to use the second form. This is because firstly, the second sort plays much nicer if you want to pass the return value to another function, and secondly, because the compiler's optimizer will deal with unnecessary copying in most cases, and thirdly because having a reference in prevents any kind of TMP from detecting the fact that it's actually a return value, and prevents the use of the function in any kind of function object context.

Comment: @GMan: Not my downvote, but 1) "prevents the use of the function in any kind of function object context" is wrong (e.g. std::for_each), 2) typical use of a function named sort (e.g. std::sort, boost::sort) is reference semantics rather than value semantics, and 3) just doesn't address the question in favor of vague, generic advice which additionally runs counter to "sort" convention.  Seems like this should be a comment.